# Probability Density Function and Expected Value of a Function of a Uniformly Distributed Variable

Tags: probability

This question pertains to the following homework question:

Let X ~ U(0,1). Find the probability density function and the expected value of X/(1-X).

How does one go about finding either?

Thus far, I've reasoned:

X being U(0,1), implies that X = 1 for 0 < X < 1, and 0 otherwise.

But doesn't this mean that X/(1-X) is undefined for 0 < x < 1, and zero otherwise? And this      would make X/(1-X) not a defined probability density function.

E[X/(1-X)] = integral of X/(1-X)dX from 0 to 1

However, this is infinity, which does not make much sense.

Where did my reasoning go wrong? Sorry I did not have the time to format decently.

Comment: Read about the _Law of the Unconscious Statistician_ (yes, searching for that phrase on Google works!) to find out how to compute $E[g(X)]$ directly from the distribution of $X$, that is, without finding the distribution of $g(X) = \frac{X}{1-X}$ first.  As far as finding the distribution of $ \frac{X}{1-X}$, can you calculate $$P\left\{\frac{X}{1-X} \leq \alpha\right\} = F_{g(X)}(\alpha)$$ for given real number $\alpha \in(0,1)$? Try it for $\alpha = \frac{1}{3}$, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random variable $X$ has (continuous) uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ precisely if for any $x$ between $0$ and $1$, we have $\Pr(X\le x)=x$.

Let $Y=\frac{X}{1-X}$. We will find the cumulative distribution function of $Y$, and then the density function.  (There are faster ways than the path we take.)

As $x$ ranges over $(0,1)$, the function $\frac{x}{1-x}$ ranges over the interval $(0,\infty)$. For any positive $y$, we now find $\Pr(Y\le y)$.

We have $Y\le y$ if and only if $\frac{X}{1-X}\le y$ if and only if $X\le (1-X)y$.

Rewrite $X\le (1-X)y$ as $X(1+y)\le y$ and then as $X\le \frac{y}{1+y}$. Since $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, we have 
$$\Pr\left(X\le \frac{y}{1+y}\right)=\frac{y}{1+y}.$$ 
It follows that the cdf $F_Y(y)$ is given by
$$F_Y(y)=\frac{y}{1+y},$$
for $0\lt y$. Differentiate to find the density function.

For the expectation of $\frac{X}{1-X}$, we can simply "calculate" $\int_0^1\frac{x\, dx}{1-x}$.  This improper integral diverges (to $\infty$). One can say the mean does not exist, or that it is infinite. We do not need to know the density or cdf of $Y$ to find $E(Y)$.