# Density function of the square root of a random number (uniformly distributed from 0 to 1)

Tags: probability, coding-theory

These questions were posted as review for material I've been covering in class.

Suppose we execute the following code:
U = MTUniform (0);
X = sqrt(U);
Here both U and X are doubles. What is the density function of X?

Suppose we execute the following code:
U = MTUniform (0);
X = -2*log(U);
Here both U and X are doubles. What is the density function of X?

I understand that the first bit of the code generates a random number from the uniform distribution 0 to 1. Then (in both questions) the random variable X is created that contains that random number that was generated. How would I find that density function? I am having a lot of trouble understanding this intuitively.

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417604)? Might help.

Comment: Also, [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573138).

Comment: And [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725754).